# Sheets batchUpdate strange error - Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a function that converts a csv to an array and update a sheet with the data.

Of 7 csv files, two give me a really weird error:

```
Error: Invalid data[0]: Requested writing within range [Sheet1!A:N], but tried writing to column [O]
```

What the hell is column[0]? This csv file has the same headers as the others. I got this error once before but the column[] had a letter in it.

My function looks like this:

```
    const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth: authorize()});
    const rows = await csv({output: "csv", noheader: true}).fromFile(filepath);

    await sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
        spreadsheetId: folderId,

        resource: {
            // How the input data should be interpreted.
            valueInputOption: 'RAW',

            // The new values to apply to the spreadsheet.
            data: [{
                range: 'Sheet1!A:N',
                majorDimension: 'ROWS',
                values: rows

            }],
        }
    }, {}, callback...
}
```

Any ideas what problem in the data is causing this (if that's the problem)?

Comment: How does the `rows` variable look like? Moreover, can you confirm that the range you have supplied is accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out this was some problem with google. I was trying for hours to figure out the problem and when I tried again the next day, I never got the error again.